# Come si gestisce l'articolo davanti ai numeri scritti in cifre?

Tags: articles, numbers

Certe volte gli italiani scrivono i numeri in cifre piuttosto che in lettere, come può accadere in frasi come

> 1) ... l'ottanta percento dei giovani è disoccupato ...,
>
> 2) ... l'undici ottobre a Roma c'è una manifestazione contro il governo ...,

e così via.

Supponiamo ora che 'ottanta' e 'undici' si vogliano scrivere in cifre, quali delle seguenti sono corrette?

> 1.a) ... l'80% dei giovani è disoccupato.
>
> 2.a) .... l'11 ottobre a Roma c'è una manifestazione contro il governo.
>
> 1.b) ... lo 80% dei giovani è disoccupato.
>
> 2.b) .... il 11 ottobre a Roma c'è una manifestazione contro il governo.

Cioè, come si gestisce l'articolo davanti ai numeri scritti in cifre?

Esattamente come se fossero scritti in lettere o ci sono regole o usi diversi?

Answer (score 4):

A mio parere 1.a e 2.a sono corrette, mentre le altre due sono errate.

Ho visto a tal proposito a volte scrivere:

> L'1 gennaio = l'uno gennaio / non corretto.

Ma in questo caso andrebbe scritto:

> Il 1° gennaio = il primo gennaio / corretto.

Come ha scritto Alb, bisogna considerarli come se fossero scritti in lettere e stare attenti a scriverli nella giusta forma.

Comment: Secondo me *uno gennaio* è corretto, perché non si discosta dagli altri giorni; *primo gennaio* forse è più comune (e certo altrettanto corretto), ma solo perché è preteso a scuola.

Comment: Questione interessante, @egreg, alla quale francamente non saprei dare una risposta!

Comment: *La festa del primo maggio* va solo così; ma *la gita si svolgerà dall'uno al tre aprile* è certamente corretto. Non vedo perché si *debba* dire *il primo ottobre* anziché *l'uno ottobre*: altrimenti si dovrebbe dire *il secondo ottobre* e così via.

Comment: Per esempio in francese si dice "primo" solo per il giorno 1, e per gli altri si usano i cardinali. Potrebbe essere così anche in italiano. Istintivamente mi suona molto meglio "il primo giugno" de "l'uno giugno".

Comment: Questione di abitudine; secondo me è la solita regola da grammatici pignoli. Insisto: *il primo dicembre* è certamente corretto, ma non può essere tacciato di errato *l'uno dicembre*.

Comment: Per quanto riguarda i giorni del mese potrebbe interessarvi [un articolo interessante](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/larticolo-date-cifre) dell'Accademia della Crusca che cita Serianni. È interessante almeno per la spiegazione storica. Non contempla però l'esempio di egreg (_«dall'uno al tre aprile»_) che potrebbe creare qualche imbarazzo (pochi se la sentirebbero di dire _«dal primo al tre aprile»_).

Answer (score 3):

Si usa l'articolo per come si pronuncia, esattamente come se fosse in lettere, sia cardinali (il 7, l'8, il 9, il 10, l'11, ecc.) che ordinali (il 1°, l'8°, ecc.).

Per precisazione sulle date, il giorno "1" del mese in italiano è sempre ordinale ("il primo"), gli altri sono sempre cardinali al singolare ("il 2, l'11, il 20"). Si dice "dal primo all'otto marzo" e non "dall'uno all'otto marzo", quindi in cifre si deve scrivere: "dal 1/3/2000 all'8/3/2000".

Comment: Che si dica "primo marzo" e non "uno marzo", non ci piove, ma hai una fonte per "dal 1/3/2000"? Semmai "dal 1º/3/2000", che però ha altri problemi. Per esempio, si dice "marzo" e non "tre", ma da tutti i punti di vista tipografici, ortografici etc. il terzo carattere della stringa "1/3/2000" è la cifra "3".

Comment: Perché mai, almeno quando si tratta di un intervallo di date, non si potrebbe dire “dall'uno all'otto marzo”? Oserei dire che è perfino preferibile, per uniformità.