# "Scrivere a lettere" versus "scrivere in lettere"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

Questa domanda mi è stata suggerita da questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/2415/707). Il quesito sarebbe: quando si deve usare "*a lettere*" e quando "*in lettere*" dopo il verbo "scrivere"?

Il post citato ha alcuni esempi che contengono l'espressione "*a lettere*":

- Scrivere *a lettere* d'oro.
- Scrivere *a lettere* da speziali.
- Scrivere *a lettere* da appigionasi.
- Scrivere *a lettere* di scatola.
- Scrivere *a lettere* maiuscole.

Ho cercato su Internet esempi di uso di "*scrivere in lettere*" e ho trovato:

- Scrivere i numeri *in lettere*.
- Scrivere una cifra *in lettere*.
- Scrivere un importo *in lettere*.

Tuttavia, non so se in questi ultimi casi si possa anche usare "*a lettere*".

**Aggiornamento:**

Sarebbe corretto dire che *"a lettere"* si usa di più in espressioni di tipo idiomatico (come quelle summenzionate), mentre *"in lettere"* è più frequentemente usato in frasi con un senso più letterale? Ad esempio, può darsi che "scrivere *a lettere* maiuscole" si usi di più nel senso figurato di "dire qualcosa con grande chiarezza" e invece con "scrivere *in lettere* maiuscole" si intenda più frequentemente un significato letterale? Ecco due frasi che illustrano quest'idea (che non so se sia corretta):

- «Meglio parlare *a lettere* maiuscole» (frase tratta da [Google Books](http://books.google.es/books?id=6N50_eCCaf4C&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%22Meglio+parlare+a+lettere+maiuscole%22&source=bl&ots=gcoee3-j9u&sig=7B1UE6A-KNrYJWeaz1E5VVU81fw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SGQxVK7GLMLUarL4gZgI&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Meglio%20parlare%20a%20lettere%20maiuscole%22&f=false)).
- «In origine l'alfabeto latino veniva scritto solo *in lettere* maiuscole che erano ben delimitate inferiormente e superiormente» (frase tratta da [Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuscolo#Origine_della_minuscola_dell.27alfabeto_latino)).

Comment: Ottimo aggiornamento.

Comment: @Charo In alcuni casi la tua intuizione potrebbe benissimo essere valida, ma avrei qualche difficoltà a generalizzarla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si può tentare di fare una ricerca sui testi letterari italiani per verificare l'uso delle diverse espressioni.

Cercare "a lettere" sui testi di [liberliber](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=09MvVKaFOquN8QeRqIC4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a+lettere%22+site:www.liberliber.it) è futile: si trova di tutto di più, ma non un numero scritto a lettere. Purtroppo cercare ["in lettere"](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=09MvVKaFOquN8QeRqIC4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22in+lettere%22+site:www.liberliber.it) è similmente poco utile: c'è troppo, e troppo poco rilevante.

Tuttavia è ragionevole supporre che "a lettere" sia simile a "a cifre" e "in lettere" sia simile a "in cifre".

Se cerchi "a cifre" su [liberliber](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=09MvVKaFOquN8QeRqIC4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a+cifre%22+site:www.liberliber.it&start=30) non troverai nulla di rilevante. Ovviamente troverai tanto di **non rilevante**: «a cifre enormi», «a cifre altissime», «a cifre grosse», «a cifre di 40 bit», «a cifre attinenti alla realtà», «a cifre romane», «a cifre inferiori», «a cifre favolose», «a cifre singolarmente diverse», «a cifre d'oro», «a cifre indelebili», «tutto a cifre numeriche», «a cifre inaudite», «a cifre tonde», «a cifre iperboliche», «ghirigoro a cifre», «a cifre dorate», «a cifre esigue», «si soggioga a cifre», «a cifre davvero molto elevate», «ridurre a cifre le umane passioni», «a cifre favolose», «a cifre leggendarie», «a cifre fantastiche», «a cifre insperabili», «a cifre di perle», «a cifre arabiche». Basta controllare per verificare che si tratta di contesti in cui l'oggetto rilevante non è la cifra per come viene scritta o riportata ma spesso qualche qualità dei caratteri che la compongono; spesso si trova in complementi che richiedono la preposizione "a".

Se cerchi ["in cifre"](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=09MvVKaFOquN8QeRqIC4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22in+cifre%22+site:www.liberliber.it&start=30), come per miracolo spuntano fuori risultati in cui l'oggetto rilevante è proprio il numero per la modalità in cui è riportato: «è in grado di indicarmi, in cifre anche approssimative, la percentuale», «calcolare in cifre», «esprimere in cifre», «ha tradotto in cifre il valore», «tradurre in cifre», «scrivere le ricette in cifre e in latino», «espose in cifre le sue entrate e i suoi esborsi», «era scritto in cifre chiarissime un numero», «in cifre tonde e facili a ricordarsi», «impresso, in cifre romane, il numero», «tradotto in cifre», «telegrammi in cifre», «numeri in cifre», «fissate in cifre», «“Vini scelti” in cifre rosse», «si ottiene in cifre», «una lettera in cifre», «scrisse qualche parola in cifre», «scrivere i numeri alla distesa, più tosto che in cifre», «registrati in cifre», «valutazione razionale della loro intensità in cifre precise», «Possiamo dire in cifre rotonde», «scritta in cifre», «È scritto in lettere e non in cifre», «rivoluzione in cifre», «addizione in cifre». A volte a "cifre" è associato un aggettivo qualificativo, ma l'oggetto d'interesse rimane il numero per come è scritto.

Sul sito della Treccani compaiono vari articoli rilevanti ([1](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/numerali_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/), [2](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_257.html), [3](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/aggettivi-numerali-ordinali_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)) in cui si dice "in lettere", "in cifre"; mai "a lettere", "a cifre" nel senso richiesto.

Sui [testi di legge](https://www.google.it/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=%22in+lettere%22+site:www.altalex.com), si dice "in cifre" e "in lettere" (si può anche cercare sul sito del [Senato](https://www.google.it/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=%22in+lettere%22+%22in+cifre%22+site:www.senato.it) e della [Camera](https://www.google.it/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=%22in+lettere%22+%22in+cifre%22+site:www.camera.it)). Si provi a fare la stessa ricerca con "a lettere" e "a cifre", non si troverà nulla di rilevante.

Si cerchi su [Google](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=09MvVKaFOquN8QeRqIC4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a+lettere%22+%22a+cifre%22) l'uso congiunto di "a lettere" e "a cifre": pochi risultati (~1.940).

Si cerchi su [Google](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=09MvVKaFOquN8QeRqIC4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22in+lettere%22+%22in+cifre%22) l'uso congiunto di "in lettere" e "in cifre": tanti risultati (~232.000).

Si cerchi su [Google Books](https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=09MvVKaFOquN8QeRqIC4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22a+lettere%22+%22a+cifre%22) l'uso congiunto di "a lettere" e "a cifre": 78 risultati.

Si cerchi su [Google Books](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=09MvVKaFOquN8QeRqIC4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22in+lettere%22+%22in+cifre%22&tbm=bks) l'uso congiunto di "in lettere" e "in cifre": 5490 occorrenze.

Qui i numeri parlano da soli.

---

Per concludere: è errato «scrivere un numero "a lettere" o "a cifre"»? No, questo non credo si possa dire. L'espressione è del tutto comprensibile. È però inusuale e forse - dico forse - sarebbe raccomandabile scrivere "in lettere" e "in cifre".

---

P.S. La mia opinione sull'utente bobie l'ho già espressa [su IL meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/repeated-abusive-behaviour-from-user). Quindi la precisazione che qui segue non è tanto per l'utente in questione quanto per l'occasionale lettore che si trovi a passare di qui, legga gli interventi molto aggressivi dell'utente e rimanga confuso dal trambusto generale.

Come si può vedere [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/628), Elberich Schneider ha proposto una modifica minore ad una risposta di Alba (che, sia detto per inciso, inspiegabilmente e senza alcun merito, ha ricevuto un bella manciata di voti); Charo ed io abbiamo approvato l'edit che modificava *"scritti a lettere"* in *"scritti in lettere"*.

Come argomento su, normalmente si scrive *"in lettere"*, non *"a lettere"*. Quindi l'edit di Elberich Schneider non è errato. Si può dire che non fosse indispensabile, e sono d'accordo: io mi sono limitato ad approvare la modifica e con quest'azione ho fondamentalmente detto "L'edit di Elberich Schneider non è senza qualche giustificazione".

[Come già spiegato](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/come-si-gestisce-larticolo-davanti-ai-numeri-scritti-in-cifre/), «i motivi per approvare un edit sono molteplici, non ultimo dar la possibilità ai nuovi utenti di partecipare più attivamente per migliorare il testo di domande e risposte, e sentirsi [così] più responsabili della qualità del sito».

Poiché non è stata introdotta alcuna imprecisione, né tantomeno alcun errore, anzi una forma rara e discutibile è stata sostituita con una forma più normale e comprensibile, nessuno avrebbe di che lamentarsi. Tuttavia, l'utente, se lo volesse, potrebbe rifiutare l'edit e nessuno si sognerebbe mai di scatenare un'edit war su una quisquilia del genere: in tanti mesi in questo sito non si è mai verificata una singola edit war, neanche su questioni ben più spinose.

Ultima osservazione: so che Alba e bobie hanno votato contro questa risposta perché li ho osservati e me ne sono accorto. Si può fare, non ho usato poteri magici, non ho corrotto gli amministratori, non ho spie infiltrate nel sistema, non ho hackerato alcun computer, non ho nemmeno ricevuto rivelazioni personali dall'alto (e nemmeno dal basso). È piuttosto il comportamento degli utenti in discussione ad essere *strano* e ad indurre, come certamente induce me, a sospettare che vi siano sockpuppet e/o meatpuppet in libera uscita per alterare il sistema di voto.

Per concludere, visto che gli abusi continuano, e continuano anche qui, in questa pagina, devo nuovamente rivolgermi ai moderatori: volete davvero che questo diventi un campo di guerra, pieno di aggressioni, insulti, ricostruzioni false, citazioni fraudolente? I troll si bannano: non ha senso esporre gli utenti onesti alle aggressioni degli utenti disonesti, a meno che non sia in corso un esperimento sociale, al quale però io non desidero prendere parte.

Comment: Per esempio, ci sono espressioni nelle quali è ugualmente usuale/corretto usare sia "in lettere" che "a lettere"? Sono state citate "scrivere *a lettere* maiuscole" (come appare nel [dizionario dei modi di dire HOEPLI](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/L/lettera.shtml)) e "scrivere *in lettere* maiuscole" (come appare nel [dizionario Italiano-Inglese Sansoni](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/M/maiuscolo.shtml)).

Comment: Immagino che in gran parte dei casi in cui si può dire "a lettere" si può anche dire "in lettere". Non mi vengono in mente controesempi (tranne ovviamente quando il complement richiede la preposizione "a"). Non è necessariamente vero il contrario.

Comment: Alba, bobie: mi piacerebbe conoscere il motivo del vostro downvote, per avere almeno un'idea su come migliorare la mia risposta.

Comment: Può darsi che "scrivere *a lettere* maiuscole" si usi di più nel senso figurato di "dire qualcosa con grande chiarezza", mentre "scrivere *in lettere* maiuscole" abbia un significato più letterale? Adesso mi sono accorta della definizione di ["scrivere *a lettere* maiuscole"](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/L/lettera.shtml#8) che fa il Dizionario dei modi di dire HOEPLI: «Scrivere o spiegarsi molto chiaramente in modo da evitare incomprensioni o malintesi, come scrivendo *in lettere* maiuscole e pertanto ben visibili.»

Comment: @bobie, I thought I made it clear: this site should be free from off-topic discussions, non-constructive criticism, and personal remarks. This kind of comments should stop right here and now. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @I.M., **bobie: mi piacerebbe conoscere il motivo del ... downvote...- randomatlabuser** . - Who told him I downvoted this answer? He is a volunteer and does not have access to the whole database. **I demand an explanation**

Comment: @bobie If you'd like to discuss some issues that have no connection to the [question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/scrivere-a-lettere-versus-scrivere-in-lettere), please do it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11367/bar-sport). Thank you for your collaboration.

Comment: _"bobie: mi piacerebbe conoscere il motivo del downvote, per  come migliorare la mia risposta."_ [I'd like to know the reason of your downvote  improve my answer]. - **This is not an answer and therefore cannot be improved,** that is the reason of my downvote. You were convinced that _'scrtitto a numeri'_ is a mistake, and **approved a wrong edit.** - After the reaction and my explanations, now you are trying **to make up a rule you do not know and you do not believe in** and disprove your edit. Any schoolboy can google search and make stats, but that is not the rule OP was asking

Answer (score 2):

'Scrivere a lettere' è corretto solo nel caso di frasi idiomatiche come, p.e., 'scritto a chiare lettere' o 'scritto a lettere maiuscole', diversamente occorre usare 'in'.

Quindi, 'scrivere le cifre/i numeri in lettere' è corretto, mentre 'scrivere le cifre/i numeri a lettere' è errato.

Comment: Io non credo sia errato dire "a lettere", persino "a cifre": è comprensibile. Tuttavia è senz'altro inusuale.

Comment: Mi sembra particolarmente significativo che nei [testi di legge](https://www.google.it/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=%22in+lettere%22+site:www.altalex.com) si dica "in cifre" e "in lettere" (si può anche cercare sul sito del [Senato](https://www.google.it/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=%22in+lettere%22+%22in+cifre%22+site:www.senato.it) e della [Camera](https://www.google.it/webhp?ie=UTF-8#q=%22in+lettere%22+%22in+cifre%22+site:www.camera.it)).

Comment: translation of answer: 'scrivere **a** lettere' is correct only in idiomatic phrases such as 'scritto a chiare lettere' or 'scritto a lettere maiuscole' = [written in capital letters]. In all other cases you must use **'in'**. Therefore 'scrivere le cifre/i numeri **in** lettere' is correct,  whereas _'scrivere i numeri **a** lettere'_ **is a mistake**

Comment: This rule is made-up and is misinformation: _'scrivere/scritto a lettere maiuscole'_ = ['written in cap letters'] is **not** an idiomatic phrase, to begin with,  and then it is also **quite correct** to say 'scritto **in** lettere maiuscole' [Dizionario Sansoni](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/M/maiuscolo.shtml).

Comment: @bobie Elberich **did not** state that "scritto in lettere maiuscole" is incorrect; he stated that "scritto a lettere maiuscole" is correct.

Comment: Penso che l'uso di ["scrivere *a lettere* maiuscole"](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/L/lettera.shtml#8) spiegato dal Dizionario dei modi di dire HOEPLI («scrivere o spiegarsi molto chiaramente in modo da evitare incomprensioni o malintesi, come scrivendo in lettere maiuscole e pertanto ben visibili») sia idiomatico.